# css3animation + box-shadow not working in Safari & Opera

Tags: safari, css, css-animations

I have implemented box-shadow effect in an div using CSS3 Animation... The code works fine in firefox and chrome but i dont know why my code is not working in Safari and Opera...

Safari Version i am using 5.1.7...

and Opera Version 12.12...

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hbATU/)

My Code:

```
@-moz-keyframes glowz {
 0%     {  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 33%    {  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 66%    {  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 100%   {  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 9px 9px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes glowz {
 0%     {  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 33%    {  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 66%    {  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 100%   {  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 9px 9px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
}
@-o-keyframes glowz {
 0%     {  -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 33%    {  -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 66%    {  -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 100%   {  -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 9px 9px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
}
@keyframes glowz {
 0%     {  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 33%    {  box-shadow:0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 66%    {  box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
 100%   {  box-shadow:0px 0px 9px 9px rgba(64,142,0,1);  }
}

.blinker {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 27px;
    left:50%; top:50%;
    border-radius: 5em; -webkit-border-radius: 5em; -moz-border-radius: 5em; -o-border-radius: 5em;

    -ms-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    -webkit-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    -moz-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    -o-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;

}
```

Is css3 animation is buggy in safari and opera ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak your CSS little bit and it will work.

**Replace Following code:**

```
    -ms-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    -webkit-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    -moz-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    -o-animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
    animation: 5s ease-in-out 0s alternate none infinite glowz;
```

**With following Code:**

```
    -webkit-animation-name: glowz;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;

    -moz-animation-name: glowz;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: none;

    -o-animation-name: glowz;
    -o-animation-duration: 5s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-direction: alternate;
    -o-animation-delay: 0;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: none;

    animation-name: glowz;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mQ8tU/)